# Dharma Type license: Bebas Neue in html5-based app

Tags: fonts, web-fonts, licensing, games, font-licensing

I want to use Bebas Neue in my commercial html5-based game for mobile devices.

1. My game mechanics implies the *use of letters as sprites*.
2. The fact that this game is html5-based game means, that *I'll put the whole font in the application distributive*.

But Dharma Type EULA imposes some restrictions:

1. You may not redistribute this font without permission.
2. You may not modify, adapt, translate, reverse engineer, decompile, disassemble, or create derivative works based on this font.

Does restriction of redistribution means that i can't use this font im my app? Does restriction of modify and adapt means that i can't make sprites from letters?

Comment: **"If it's a good idea, go ahead and do it. It is much easier to apologize than it is to get permission"** - [Grace Hopper](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper). Though probably not cheaper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the font file *implies* that you aren't re-distributing the font file, as you aren't putting the file itself into your app.

Will downloading your app allow me to extract the font file and use it on my own machine? Are you copying the font file as-is into the app? If the answer to either is 'no', then you should have a good case for including it and not break your license agreement.

A better idea though, is to contact Dharma type and ask them. If their answer is 'you can't', they'll probably be happy to quote you for a license that makes them go 'yes, you can'.

Comment: I've got the answer from author:
_"The license is old version.
Now, Bebas Neue is licensed under SIL Open Font license.
This means you can use the font for free for commercial use, you can distribute the font, you can modify and create derivative work.
So, There is no problem to use the font in html5-based game. Of course you can sell the game."_

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

I have given the link just as example.You have to check the licensing with your font type whether it is available for the particular use or not.

http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/flat-it/dharma-gothic/licensing.html

Font for application uses and see the EULA.